# Image URL leads to "Not found page"

Tags: wordpress, image, url, media

Images are working fine in the site. but when I copy an image url and put it on browser, It leads to a "Not found page".

My wordpress site: horinbranding.com

Test an image: http://horinbranding.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/robot.png

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There can be three reasons for the above problem. Checking and correcting them can solve your issue.

1. Missing of `attachment.php` in the theme folder. So add `attachment.php` page to the theme folder.
2. Incorrect permalink structure. So set the permalink structure to default.
3. Improper `.htaccess` file. So create a new `.htaccess` file.